# Static members of a Class

Tags: java, static

I am beginner in JAVA, I was reading this code:

```
class trying1{
    static int x =40;
    public static void main(String ...s){
        trying1 t = new trying1();
        x =20;
        System.out.println(x); // print 20
        t.show1();
    }

    void show1(){
        System.out.println(x); // print 20
    }

}

class trying2{
    public static void main(String ...s){
    System.out.println(trying1.x); // print 40
    }
}
```

Why does it print **40** in  class **trying2** ?

I know that static data members get memory only once and everyone shares that memory. As in Class **trying1**,  **'x'** is a class var, & if I change the value of **x** it will be  reflected in every instance of class or you can say it value will been changed at its memory location. aAfter compiling and running class **trying1**,  if I run **trying2.class** it shows **40** as output.

However its value should have been changed to 20?

Can someone help me out in this.

Thank you!!

Comment: how do you run this?

Comment: **javac trying1.java**,  hence two  '.class'  files are created you can run either of them using java command.

Comment: means you start trying1, it runs, ends, next you start trying2, it runs too .. ?

Comment: obvisouly .. whats the issue with this

Answer (score 1):

If you start trying2, you start another JVM. The first instance of the JVM, that was using trying1 as the main class, is stopped, and whatever trying1.main(...) did, has no effect on the second JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cause you never persist the new value, and every time x=40

Comment: Can it be related to class loading or running time, that the static member get memory at class loading time

Comment: there are two isolated runs, two mains, two execs and no one persist